# Python combo chart add the percentage on the bar but wrong

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I tried to add the percentage on the bar in combo chart, line and column graphs.
However, all the values displayed are messy.

I provide the data here, this is also my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384157/python-bar-and-line-chart-with-groups-in-one-graph/56384957?noredirect=1#comment99372024_56384957) and the answer is provided by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384957/7651845).

```
Group   yq        Value1    Value2
G       2014Q1     0.07        1.1
G       2014Q2     0.06        1.09
G       2014Q3     0.09        1.11
G       2014Q4     0.04        1.13
I       2014Q1     0.10        1.2
I       2014Q2     0.13        1.25
I       2014Q3     0.15        1.23
I       2014Q4     0.18        1.4
```

I provided the code I tried:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
ax2=ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='yq',y='Value2', data=dataset, hue='Group', ax=ax1, legend = None)
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticks(), rotation=45)
ax1.set_ylabel("")
ax1.set_ylim((min(dataset['Value2']) - 0.05, max(dataset['Value2']) + 0.05))
sns.barplot(x='yq', y='Value1', data=dataset, hue='Group',ax=ax2)
ax2.set_yticklabels(['{:.1f}%'.format(a*100) for a in ax2.get_yticks()])
ax2.set_ylabel("")
for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    ax2.text(row.name,row['Value1'], '{:.1f}%'.format(round(row['Value1'],2)), color='black')
plt.show()
```

The percentages showing on the plot are messy and do not place properly on each bar and group.
I searched on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/seaborn-barplot-displaying-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917587/matplotlib-advanced-bar-plot/19919397#19919397) but I cannot solve it.
Any solution?

I provide my result:
[image]

I also provide the correct resulting image created by `R`'s package `ggplot2`.
There are two packages similar to `ggplot2` in `Python`, `plotnine` and `ggplot`. However, I cannot use it in my Python.
[image]

I provide my R code as your reference if it helps:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
dataset <- fread("Group   yq        Value1    Value2
G       2014/1/1     0.07        1.1
G       2014/4/1     0.06        1.09
G       2014/7/1     0.09        1.11
G       2014/10/1     0.04        1.13
I       2014/1/1     0.10        1.2
I       2014/4/1     0.13        1.25
I       2014/7/1     0.15        1.23
I       2014/10/1     0.18        1.4", header = T)
dataset$yq <- as.Date(dataset$yq)
dataset[, yq := as.yearqtr(dataset$yq, format = "%Y-%m-%d")]

ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = yq, colour = Group, fill = Group,
                           label = scales::percent(Value1, accuracy = 0.1))) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = sec_axis_mult * Value1), position = position_dodge2(width = 0)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Value2)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue"), labels = c("G", "I")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue"), labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", breaks = unique(dataset$yq)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Value2",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./sec_axis_mult, name = "Value1",
                                         labels = scales::percent)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, size = 12, vjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_blank(),
        legend.position="left",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background =  element_blank()) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 10))) +
  geom_text(data = dataset, aes(y = sec_axis_mult * Value1, colour = Group), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.25),
            vjust = -0.3, size = 4)
```

Comment: Can you embed an image of the resulting plot?

Comment: I added on it and also provide the desired plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm doing is dynamically labeling the bar graphs based on the coordinates for each patch that's drawn by the bar function.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
ax2=ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='yq',y='Value2', data=dataset, hue='Group', ax=ax1, legend = None)
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticks(), rotation=45)
ax1.set_ylabel("")
ax1.set_ylim((min(dataset['Value2']) - 0.05, max(dataset['Value2']) + 0.05))
sns.barplot(x='yq', y='Value1', data=dataset, hue='Group',ax=ax2)
ax2.set_yticklabels(['{:.1f}%'.format(a*100) for a in ax2.get_yticks()])
ax2.set_ylabel("")
#iterate through each group of bars
for group in ax2.containers:
    for bar in group:
        #label the bar graphs based on the coordinates of the bar patches
        ax2.text(
            bar.get_xy()[0]+bar.get_width()/2,
            bar.get_height(), 
            '{:.1f}%'.format(round(100*bar.get_height(),2)), 
            color='black',
            horizontalalignment='center'
        )
```

Output:
[image]

I've adjusted the code to more closely match the desired output that's been added to the original question.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
ax2=ax1.twiny().twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='yq',y='Value2', data=dataset, hue='Group', ax=ax1, legend = None)
ax1.set_xticklabels(dataset['yq'], rotation=45)
ax1.set_ylabel("")
ax1.set_ylim((0, max(dataset['Value2']) + 0.05))
ax2.set_ylim(0, max(dataset['Value2']) + 0.05)
sns.barplot(x='yq', y='Value1', data=dataset, hue='Group',ax=ax2)

#iterate through each group of bars
for group in ax2.containers:
    for bar in group:
        #label the bar graphs based on the coordinates of the bar patches
        ax2.text(
            bar.get_xy()[0]+bar.get_width()/2,
            bar.get_height(), 
            '{:.1f}%'.format(100*bar.get_height()), 
            color='black',
            horizontalalignment='center'
        )

ax1.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
```

Outputs:
[image]

Comment: Personally, I would use [PercentFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/ticker_api.html) to render percentages, but I kept my code consistent with how the question labeled percentages.

Comment: Could you also provide `PercentFormatter`'s code that you will user to draw?

Comment: PercentFormatter doesn't draw on the axis. You can format the ticks on the axis. In your original code you labeled all the ticks with percent, but you can just set the axis ticker to PercentFormatter and then decimal values will be labeled as percentages.

Comment: OK. Is it possible to make line and bar apart the plot I provide above? It seems that bar will cover the line.

Comment: I tried to align the text color by their groups. I modified `color = group` in the `ax2.text` but got error

Comment: ```group``` is an array of bar container objects. Each bar should have a facecolor property, but I do not recommend making the text the same color as the bar as it will make it hard to read.

Comment: Try ```color=bar.get_facecolor()``` Also if you want red and blue as the colors. You can change the seaborn palette.

Comment: the second plot you draw shows label and tick of x-axis on the top. It seems weird

Comment: I would recommend using `annotate` instead of `text` and apply some offset just as shown in [the matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html).