# Aligning line and grouped bar charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, line-plot, grouped-bar-chart

I am trying to plot a line chart on top of a bar chart using Python's pandas library. The bar chart is a clustered chart from a DataFrame and looks like so when plotted by itself:

[Clustered Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VPch.png)

The line chart is the averages across the whole dataset:

[Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFoqV.png)

I can successfully plot both sets of data on the same axis object if using all line charts:

[All Line Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zey7b.png)

But when I switch the DataFrame for the clustered bar to actually using a bar chart and plot it along with the line chart, the line chart wants to plot from the second index position, leading to an offset.

[Bar and Line With Offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1b8m.png)

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384157/python-bar-and-line-chart-with-groups-in-one-graph) has an interesting comment about the way matplotlib treats the x-axis for both bar and line charts, which may be relevant here, but I can't work out what to do with that insight.

What's a good way to fix this alignment issue?

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

table_data = {2019: {1: np.nan,
2: np.nan,
3: np.nan,
  4: 1.4200000000000002,
  5: 0.8193548387096775,
  6: 1.420689655172414,
  7: 0.4645161290322581,
  8: 0.10322580645161289,
  9: 0.29333333333333333,
  10: 1.7741935483870968,
  11: 0.32,
  12: 6.703225806451614},
 2020: {1: 5.52,
  2: 12.613793103448277,
  3: 0.9428571428571428,
  4: 0.1793103448275862,
  5: 0.39354838709677414,
  6: 1.3866666666666667,
  7: 1.9800000000000002,
  8: 0.6689655172413793,
  9: 0.19333333333333336,
  10: 5.896774193548388,
  11: 0.6896551724137931,
  12: 4.103225806451613},
 2021: {1: 2.7935483870967746,
  2: 5.15,
  3: 9.696774193548388,
  4: 3.74,
  5: 2.8967741935483873,
  6: 0.9103448275862069,
  7: 1.6516129032258065,
  8: 0.3,
  9: 0.38571428571428573,
  10: 5.141935483870968,
  11: 8.58,
  12: 6.052173913043479},
 2022: {1: 2.3923076923076922,
  2: 31.678571428571427,
  3: 8.761290322580646,
  4: np.nan,
  5: np.nan,
  6: np.nan,
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan,
  9: np.nan,
  10: np.nan,
  11: np.nan,
  12: np.nan}}

means = {1: 3.6137931034482755,
 2: 16.435294117647057,
 3: 7.132530120481928,
 4: 1.797752808988764,
 5: 1.3698924731182796,
 6: 1.240909090909091,
 7: 1.358695652173913,
 8: 0.3522727272727273,
 9: 0.28863636363636364,
 10: 4.2709677419354835,
 11: 3.2247191011235956,
 12: 5.578823529411765}

df_bars = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
df_means = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(means, orient = 'index', columns = ['Mean'])

# Clustered bar chart by itself
df_bars.plot(kind = 'bar',
           title = 'Average Daily Rainfall by Month',
           ylabel = 'Average Daily Rainfall (mm)',
           figsize = (10, 6)
          )

# Line chart by itself
df_means.plot(
    kind = 'line',
    title = 'Average Daily Rainfall by Month',
    ylabel = 'Average Daily Rainfall (mm)',
    y = 'Mean'
)

# Show all data as line charts. This works OK
ax_avg = df_bars.plot(kind = 'line',
           title = 'Average Daily Rainfall by Month',
           ylabel = 'Average Daily Rainfall (mm)',
           figsize = (10, 6)
          )

df_means.plot(
    ax = ax_avg,
    kind = 'line',
    y = 'Mean'
)
plt.show()

# Show bar data and line chart on the one plot. The line chart is offset!
ax_avg2 = df_bars.plot(kind = 'bar',
           title = 'Average Daily Rainfall by Month',
           ylabel = 'Average Daily Rainfall (mm)',
           figsize = (10, 6)
          )

df_means.plot(
    ax = ax_avg2,
    kind = 'line',
    y = 'Mean'
)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reset_index` to change the indexing of line dataframe back to start with zero.

This will allow your bars to line up with zero-based indexing like this:

```
ax_avg2 = df_bars.plot(kind = 'bar',
           title = 'Average Daily Rainfall by Month',
           ylabel = 'Average Daily Rainfall (mm)',
           figsize = (10, 6)
          )

df_means.reset_index().plot(
    ax = ax_avg2,
    kind = 'line',
    y = 'Mean'
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm after. Many thanks @Scott!